# Semantic Versioning in dApps

Tags: solidity, dapps

In semantic versioning [documentation](https://semver.org/), the first digit is described as:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes

To my understanding I think it makes more sense to increment MAJOR when contract interfaces are changed, since interfaces are like an API.

Is it correct to think an interface as a kind of API and make the versioning according to the statement above ?

Thanks